# Можно ли подружить Visual Studio Code и TFS <2015?

Tags: visual-studio-code, контроль-версий, tfs

Подскажите, есть ли возможность подружить Visual Studio Code с TFS версии < 2015?

Из плагинов видел только официальный, но он как раз для TFS>=2015...

Есть еще какие-то варианты?

Или может быть можно сделать так, что бы TFS или параллельно запущенная вижуалка детектила изменения, что бы потом их через Visual Studi 2017 можно было залить.

Comment: Любопытно, а зачем это? что мешает использовать текущую версию tfs? Они же вроде без потерь апгрейдятся в верх.

Comment: @NewView новая денег стоит=)

Comment: Однако :) не знал..так как не пользуюсь, это для меня маленькое открытие.. Плагин имеет смысл поискать на гитхабе, там среди частных наработок толковые решения попадают.

Comment: @NewView ну это майки. У них все платное в корпоративном сегменте...

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что используется как весионный контроль.

1. Если гит, то клонируете репозиторий и комит через студию или командную строку.
2. Если TFVC, то используете локальную рабочую область ([Decide between using a local or a server workspace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops)), она контролирует изменения вне студии. Еще можно итеграцию с проводником использовать: [Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention)